# Spring Security still returns HTTP 403 when HTTP request is created from remote host

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

**Situation**

This is my Spring security config and it works when I create request from `localhost` and application runs at `localhost` too.

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/client/**")
        .hasRole(HttpClientType.CLIENT.name())
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .hasRole(HttpClientType.USER.name())
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .accessDeniedHandler(restAuthorizationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable().cors().disable();

  }
```

**Problem**

When I deploy my application to production server, and create request from remote host, every time I get `HTTP 403`.

*P.S. I thought the problem will be in `CORS` and `CSRF` but it doesn't work even I disable it.*

Comment: Try making the request from Postman or cUrl. If it is CORS the Postman request should succeed.

Comment: I am using Postman and `Authentication` is successful.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure it's CORS issue. Spring Security is pretty non-intuitive when using `.cors().disable()`. The `cors().disable()` does not disable cors security filter at all, but only applies the default cors configurations

Comment: I don't think CORS would return a 403. Try removing `.antMatchers("/**").hasRole(...)` and change to `.anyRequest().hasRole(...)` instead of `.anyRequest().authenticated()`.

Comment: Are you using an embedded servlet container? Or deploying on an external web container like Tomcat?

Comment: Look at the error via `wget --content-on-error`?

Comment: I'm also wondering what you're deploying the application to, and how it manages the app. Are you deploying using Tomcat with a context path? (e.g. *myremotehost.domain.com/myapp/client/abc*) or a Spring Boot app that runs at the root of a virtual host? (e.g. *myremotehost.domain.com/client/abc*)

Comment: Are u using contextpath in both the condition?

Answer (score 1):

The `cors().disable()` does not disable cors security filter at all, but only applies the default cors configurations.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    ...
    .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
    ...
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(CorsConfiguration.ALL)); 
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
  
   // ideally CorsConfiguration.ALL should not be used in production

    configuration.addExposedHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION); // The headers you expose in response

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();       
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

    return source;
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using @EnableWebSecurity in the class to enable mvc security settings?. Test with .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())

```
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```